# Displaying own map in android

Tags: android

I want to display the map of college. I already have blueprint of college and also know the lat and longitude. Is there any way to achieve this, if so then please help me. I want to display map like this..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNktm.png)
  Thanks in advance

Comment: this might help https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: Thanks. I will check it

Answer (score 1):

you can use GoogleAPI for it, using lattitude and longitude you can plot your college location.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to display my own blueprint and add marker on it. I modified my question and added the link of image.